# How to save twurl output on Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: curl, twitter, amazon-ec2

I'm new to Amazon EC2 and Ruby and I managed to run twurl (similar to cURL) on an micro instance on EC2 (linux).

My goal is to capture tweets for specific keywords (using twurl and the Streaming API) with an EC2 instance.

I established a connection to the Twitter Streaming API and now I have all the tweets coming in on the terminal window..

`twurl -t -d track=obama  -H stream.twitter.com /1.1/statuses/filter.json > raw-tweets.json`

I'm wondering how to save this output to a file (also I need to stop the script/command at some time because right now tweets are coming in indefinitely) and then download this file. As you can see above I added `>raw-tweets.json` at the end but I don't know if that works and where/how to locate that file and download it to my local computer?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that is has actually been saved. The only question remaining is how to terminate the twurl command after a certain time period?